# Get selected checkbox in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

code below is from my View

```
  <input  type="radio" name="gender"  id="Male" vale="Male" /> Male
  <input  type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" vale="Female" /> Female
  <input  type="radio" name="gender" id="Unisex" vale="Unisex" /> Unisex
```

In my controller if I am using:

```
string gender = formData["gender"];
```

I only get `on` , I am not sure which option user have selected.

Any help please.

Comment: so you dont "get off"

Comment: Your `value` attribute is wrong it should `value="Female"` not  `vale="Female"`

Comment: Thanks very much. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

You can take it by HttpPost method

```
<input  type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female" /> 
<input  type="radio" name="gender" id="Unisex" value="Unisex" />

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(string gender)
{
      //Your Action Code Here
}
```

You could always access it from the `Request.Form`

```
var YourRadioButton = Request.Form["gender"];
```